# Passing two lists to pandas_udf in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am trying to calculate the euclidean distance between the corresponding pairs. I have tried using normal udf and it works fine. I want to try using `pandas_udf` to make it faster.

```
@pandas_udf(T.FloatType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def calculate_euclidean_distance(feature1, feature2):
    from scipy.spatial import distance
    dist = float(distance.euclidean(feature1, feature2))
    return float(dist)
```

This is how the data looks like. The columns feature1 and feature2 are two lists of the same dimension.

```
all_pairs_remove_same_pair_df.select("feature1", "feature2").show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|            feature1|            feature2|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....|
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....|
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....|
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....|
|[2.23668528E8, 1....|[2.23668528E8, 1....|

all_pairs_remove_same_pair_df.withColumn("distance", calculate_euclidean_distance(array(F.col("feature1"), F.col("feature2"))))
```

This is error I am getting -

```
TypeError: calculate_euclidean_distance() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feature2'
```

Comment: the referred post is not an exact duplicate - specifically, you shouldn't pass the columns in an array but as separate columns:   all_pairs_remove_same_pair_df.withColumn("distance", calculate_euclidean_distance(F.col("feature1"), F.col("feature2")))

Comment: Found the solution. Didn't know that the values are pandas `pandas.core.series.Series`  in pandas_udf. Anyway Thanks.
` @pandas_udf(T.FloatType(), PandasUDFType.SCALAR)`
`def calculate_euclidean_distance(feature1, feature2):`
    `from scipy.spatial import distance`
   ` import pandas as pd`
    `features_df = pd.DataFrame({"feature1": feature1, "feature2": feature2})`
   ` features_df["euclidean_distance"] = features_df.apply(lambda x: distance.euclidean(x["feature1"], x["feature2"]), axis=1)`
    `return features_df["euclidean_distance"] `